# RegisterJsObject CefSharp not work

Tags: javascript, c#, wpf, cefsharp

I have that problem whith CefSharp and js communication. 
This is my structure. In my MainWindow.xaml.cs I have:

```
chromium = new CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser();
chromium.RegisterJsObject("jsInterface", new jsMapInterface());
```

where **jsMapInterface** is a public class with its methods.

In my html/js folder, I call a C# method with:

```
window.jsInterface.myTest();
//jsInterface.myTest();  //I have tested twice
```

where myTest() is a method inside **jsMapInterface** class but nothing happens. Where is my mistake?

Thanks in advise.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try UpperCasing on the C# side e.g `MyTest()` as mentioned under **Please note** in https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#3-how-do-you-expose-a-net-class-to-javascript

CefSharp does perform name mangling. The reason is it tries to encourage following JS conventions on the JS side and C# conventions on that side.

Finally work from the example code at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=BoundObject

Comment: I resolved!! I write MyTest() in the C# side and myTest() in js side. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Hi I guess I may be late on this... but everything looks like it's wired up fine to me... but maybe you should keep a modular ref to `new jsMapInterface()` to ensure it's not destroyed/cleaned up.

Comment: Though generally good advice to `var MyJsMapInterface = new jsMapInterface();` e.g together with instantiation of `browser` and then using that var in your `RegisterJsObject()` call I don't think it's the issue here. At least the example code search I gave in my second link does the same as @salvo italy. I suspect it works because the `RegisterJsObject` call holds on to a reference to the object so it won't get garbage collected.